# how to check if object have viewControllers array

Tags: objective-c, ios5, nsarray, viewcontroller

How do i check if object types id have viewcontrollers array.
I need check if i can call viewControllers. Is it correct to call respondsToSelector?

```
while (![obj isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]])
{
obj = [obj viewControllers].lastObject;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (class_getProperty([obj class], "viewControllers") != NULL)
```

you need to import `#import <objc/runtime.h>`

Answer (score 0):

Only UINavigationController, UISplitViewController , UITabBarController has viewControllers property.

```
 if([obj isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
 {
    if([obj viewControllers])
       //has view controllers
 }
 else if([obj isKindOfClass:[UISplitViewController class]])
 {
    if([obj viewControllers])
       //has view controllers
 }
 else if([obj isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]])
 {
    if([obj viewControllers])
       //has view controllers
 }
```